# How to set text above footer in pdf using pdf reactor

Tags: html, css, pdf-reactor

We use Pdf reactor in our web application. We render footer using running elements with pdf reactor tool. The footer is placed by using the below code.

```
@bottom-center{
   content:element(footer);
}
```

Now I have a pdf report disclosure. How can I set the disclosure always above the footer.

Tried using:

```
'#footer_disclosure{
position:absolute;
bottom:-88px;
}'
```

But this is not giving me the correct result always as it is sometimes gets overlapped on footer.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include your `#footer_disclosure` element inside your running `footer` element.
Then you add CSS rules to make sure the disclosure is where you want it.